# AWS Step Functions permission for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless

How to give permission for lambda to invoke a stepfunction state machine in serverless YAML?

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the `states:StartExecution` method as allowed in [the lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). You will also need to make sure that the step function that you want to start is part of the resources you're allowed to start.

Comment: Could use a little detail

Comment: The link in the answer will give you all the detail you need.

Comment: Make sure the step function's role has this permission and if you are doing this manually as your user to test it, then that user will also need the permissions. Depends on your specific error though this seems to be the role needing it right now. Many AWS servers, especially when using the console, require parts of other services to function or be viewed in the console.